# Add text to the shape in center

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a view that looks like this :

[image]

I want to add a text label to each segment in the view such that it aligns in the center. Each of the segment is a customized button that also responds when in the layer specified. When I try to do button.setTitle, since the frame for the button is different, it doesn't align with the shape layer. Can anyone advise as to how to achieve the same.

I tried creating another function and calling it while creating the shape and the buttons.

```
func addText(_ stringValue: String, to shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            let textlayer = CATextLayer()
            if let rect = shapeLayer.path?.boundingBox {
//                print(rect)
                textlayer.frame = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x + rect.size.width/2, y:rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2, width: 20, height: 20)
                textlayer.fontSize = 12
                textlayer.alignmentMode = .center
                textlayer.string = stringValue
                textlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                textlayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                shapeLayer.addSublayer(textlayer)
            }
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work as the text is getting overlapped to the layer. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve the same?

**EDIT :**

Each segment has text, I just added a few of them to give an idea.

[image]

**EDIT 2 :**

The code to create the view :

```
        for segment in outerSegments { 
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i]
            let label = CATextLayer()

            //addText(data[i], to: shape)
            let b = MyButton(type: .custom)
            b.path = path
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            b.tag = Int(data[i].asciiValues[0])
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            let frameRect = shape.bounds
            b.frame = frameRect
            let sine = sin(startAngle)
            let cosine = cos(startAngle)
            print("\(sine)  \(data[i])")
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.addSubview(b)
            self.bringSubviewToFront(b)
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            //layer.addSublayer(shape)
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
        valueCount = innerSegments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})
        startAngle = 0
        i = 100
        for segment in innerSegments {
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: 2*radius/3, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i-100]
            addText(data[i-100], to: shape)
            let b = MyButton(type: .custom)
            b.path = path
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            let frameRect = shape.bounds
            b.frame = frameRect
            b.tag = Int(data[i-100].asciiValues[0])

            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.addSubview(b)
            self.bringSubviewToFront(b)

            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            //layer.addSublayer(shape)
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
        valueCount = innerMostSegments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})
        startAngle = 0
        i = 1000
        for segment in innerMostSegments {
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius/3, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i-1000]
            addText(data[i-1000], to: shape)
            let b = MyButton(type: .custom)
            b.path = path
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            let frameRect = shape.bounds
            b.frame = frameRect
            b.tag = Int(data[i-1000].asciiValues[0])
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInsid)
            self.addSubview(b)
            self.bringSubviewToFront(b)
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you don't use different views and rotate each?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I didn't get you there, could you explain a little bit.

Comment: Could you draw e.g. in standard `Preview`  app (View->Show markup toolbar) how the text should look like?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk I have added the output that I desire, That might be of help

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using math to calculate the "spokes" and "arcs"?

For each segment, you probably need to bisect the angles that make up the sides (the yellow line), then calculate a point (the red dot) along that line midway between the arcs:

[image]

That point becomes the center of the label's frame.

Comment: I created the path using `let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)` So I can obtain sine and cosine of the start and end angles. I am not sure how to calculate this. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @dper - is each "section" a `UIView`? Or is the entire drawing one view? If you show the code you're using to generate your view, it'll be much easier for me to help with the calculations.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code to create the segments. Hope that helps you which in turn helps me :P

Comment: I tried adding setTitle to the buttons as well, but the title goes to the middle of the button frame which is rectangular and not the segment. I also thought of trying a way using button.contentEdgeInsets and try applying the layout using it but no sucess

Comment: @dper - end of day for me. I can take another look at this in the morning.

Comment: Sure thanks for the help, waiting for your morning now :)

Comment: I was able to identify the point using `let point = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(CGFloat(i) * incrementAngle) * radius * 1.5 * ratio, y: origin.y + sin(CGFloat(i) * incrementAngle) * radius * 1.5 * ratio)` and create textLayer around that point. The problem is that this point lies on the line(green dotted). I want to get  the point 15 degrees clockwise to the point obtained.

Comment: It would be great if I can connect and discuss this issue. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214985/chat-to-discuss-the-query